# Referencing section of php code

Tags: php, mysql, variables, reference

I have the following PHP code on my site which basically accesses a PHP script that pulls out information from a mysql table;

```
<?php include('event_connect.php'); ?>
```

Is it possible to include a reference to a specific section of code in this script?

Basically I have to create 39 different scripts for individual dropdown e.g. in the "XXX" drop down, only records with an identifier "xxx" will show up.

What i thought would be easier than createing 39 scripts is (if possible) just add some sort of reference value to the above code depending on where in the page it is placed. Kind of like how VBA allows you to call a selected function from another...

**Edit: This is the PHP i use to access the mysql database, with the code provided by niet added in - works a treat! Thank you.**

```
<?php
//Get te CSS styling

// Make a MySQL Connection

mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "xxxx" table

switch($section) {
case 1:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Events_List` WHERE `Value` = 'value_1' LIMIT 0 , 30") or die(mysql_error());  
break;

case 2:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Events_List` WHERE `Value` = 'value_2' LIMIT 0 , 30") or die(mysql_error());  
break;

// store the records of the "xxxx" table into $row array and loop through

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   $name = $row['name'];   

$Event = $row['Event'];   
$Date = $row['Date'];   
$Type = $row['Type'];   
$Description = $row['Description'];      
$Event = htmlspecialchars($row['Event'],ENT_QUOTES);   
$Date = htmlspecialchars($row['Date'],ENT_QUOTES);   
$Type = htmlspecialchars($row['Type'],ENT_QUOTES);   
$Description = htmlspecialchars($row['Description'],ENT_QUOTES);      


echo " <div id='ev_con'>
<div id='ev_img'> </div>
<div id='Event'> $Event </div>
<div id='Date'> $Date </div>
<div id='Type'> $Type </div>
<div id='Description'>  $Description </div> 
</div>";}

?>
```

This runs one query fine, but having trouble getting multiple queries running..

Comment: I honestly can't figure out what your question means. I don't think you are asking if PHP has variables or functions, are you?

Comment: use "require_once()" instead of "include()" for startes and then look us some tutorials on php functions.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, i think (and am hoping) that Niet and Marty have got the answer below, at a glance it makes sense and looks like it on the right track! Arrok - Lots of tutorials online, but not always useful for specific needs. Have always found stack overflow to be one of the best sources for figuring out coding problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$section = 1;
include("event_connect.php");
```

And in your event_connect file:

```
switch($section) {
case 1:
    // do things
    break;
case 2:
    // do other things
    break;
// ...
}
```

Comment: would that not need to be a require() then?

Comment: Hi Niet, as with Marty's post, this looks like a good start. Id rep up the answer if i could! I will give both your code and the code Marty posted a try! Thanks for sharing!!

Comment: So, tried this but did not work. FYI, the event_connect.php is provided below:

Comment: Ok, sorry for my bumbling!! After some trial and error i realised the problem was the syntax in the sql - did not like using double qoutes in the sql, I have updated my sql above to show the code that works! This now displays specific events on different accordion drop downs on the same page - amazingly useful code!

Comment: p.s. I have actually learned a lot about php from investigating this issue - thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

how about...

```
function get_event_connect($eventID){
    switch($eventID){
        case "1" :
          // output code
        break;

        case "2" :
          //output code
        break;
    }
}


$eventID = "1";
echo get_event_connect($eventID);
```

Comment: Hi Marty, looks like a start - while I dont have much knowledge of PHP the way you have set out the cases makes sense to me, different syntax but quite similar to VBA.. ..I will give this a shot!